# SQL Server Optimize Query with Optional Columns And Joined Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, query-optimization

I'm looking for some advice on how to optimize the query below

- `PatientId` and `PracticeId` are PKs
- None of the 6 columns (*PhoneNumber and *PhoneCountryCode) are indexed
- `pp.PracticePatientStatus` is not indexed
- `PhoneNumber` columns are all defined as `NVARCHAR(10)`

My questions are:

- How to create the index on the 6 columns? Should it be 1 index on 6 columns (if yes, in what order?) or it should be 6 indexes one per column?
- Does the index behave differently when there is AND or OR between the columns?
- Also what to do with `pp.PracticePatientStatus`, should I create a separate index on it?

Here is the query

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.UDTTable_PhoneSearch AS TABLE 
(
    PhoneCountryCode SMALLINT     NOT NULL,
    PhoneNumber      NVARCHAR(10) NOT NULL
);
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Search_Patients_ByPhone
    (@RowCount INT,
     @PracticeId INT,
     @Filter dbo.UDTTable_PhoneSearch READONLY,
     @IncludeInactivePatients BIT)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT TOP (@RowCount) *
    FROM dbo.Patient AS p WITH (NOLOCK)
    INNER JOIN dbo.PracticePatient pp ON p.PatientId = pp.PatientId 
                                      AND pp.PracticeId = @PracticeId
    INNER JOIN @Filter f ON (p.PatientCellPhoneNumber = f.PhoneNumber AND COALESCE(p.PatientCellPhoneCountryCode, 1) = f.PhoneCountryCode)
                         OR (p.PatientHomePhoneNumber = f.PhoneNumber AND COALESCE(p.PatientHomePhoneCountryCode, 1) = f.PhoneCountryCode)
                         OR (p.PatientWorkPhoneNumber = f.PhoneNumber AND COALESCE(p.PatientWorkPhoneCountryCode, 1) = f.PhoneCountryCode)
    WHERE 
        @IncludeInactivePatients = 1 
        OR pp.PracticePatientStatus = 1
    ORDER BY 
        p.PatientId DESC 
END;
```

Comment: The problem is syntax like `COALESCE(p.PatientCellPhoneCountryCode, 1)`; this makes your query non-SARGable. Try check for `NULL` instead: perhaps `(p.PatientCellPhoneNumber = f.PhoneNumber AND (p.PatientCellPhoneCountryCode = f.PhoneCountryCode OR p.PatientCellPhoneCountryCode  IS NULL))`

Comment: Please show your full table and index schema. Please also share the query plan via https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan. this question is not really answerable otherwise

Comment: @Charlieface, the table of concern is proprietary, I won't be able to share the whole thing... But the main parts are shown... My question is mainly about indexes on the phone number fields... Should I create 1 index on all of them, or 6 indexes one per each column?

Comment: Then you can anonymize the plan using SentryOne Plan Explorer, and show anonymized sample data. We can't work on nothing

Answer (score 1):

You might be better off to normalize your data such that you have a patient record, thus a patient ID.

THEN, have a PhoneNumbers table with the Patient ID, a column for the type of phone (home, work, cell, other) and the actual phone.  Then you can have an index on the phone and patient ID that it ties back to, then you are able to query on just the one phone column to match regardless of the type.

```
select
      p.PatientID,
      p.LastName,
      ph.Phone,
      etc...
   from
      Phones ph
         join @Filter f
            on ph.Phone = f.PhoneNumber
           AND ph.PhoneCountryCode = f.PhoneCountryCode
         join Patient p
            on ph.PatientID = p.PatientID
         join PracticePatient pp
            on ph.PatientId = pp.PatientId
   where
       .. now, apply your conditions for patient practice conditions
```

The "Phones" table should have an index on `(Phone, PhoneCountryCode, PatientId)` to allow direct tie back to the patient table.

Just a suggestion for ONE possible solution.